# Dynamically Populate Email Name?

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, email

I am wondering if there is a way to use AMPScript to dynamically populate email name. We fill in email name in our URL string, but we need to create multiple emails with different email names if we want to segment customers differently based on email name.  I am wondering if I can write some AMPScript code to populate different email names instead?

Answer (score 0):

Not with AMPScript, but with the [ET/SFMC API](https://code.exacttarget.com/apis-sdks/).

AMPScript is evaluated *inside* existing emails and landing pages.  Following your scenario, the email would need to be created before you'd have a chance to utilize AMPScript.

If you use the ET/SFMC API, you can [create the Email](http://help.exacttarget.com/en-US/technical_library/web_service_guide/technical_articles/creating_an_email_via_the_web_service_api/) however you want.